# Order Receive Relationship

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-boot, erd

I have a relationship model like this

[image]

The idea is, partial order can be received, that is, a Receive will have multiple entry of same Order. On the other hand, a Order will have multiple entry of same Receive. For clear understanding please see this image,

[image]

Data can be saved easily. But, while I try to show the details of a Receive (say, Receive -1), I can not show the right **received quantity** against a particular item of a Order, all other information are shown correctly. In short, data saves in Receive Details quite nicely, but can not retrieve correctly.

Can you please tell what is wrong with this model or please suggest me a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your first diagram does not illustrate a relationship between your `Receive-1`/`Receive-2` tables and your order `Item` table.  I'm not sure if this is an oversight because your second diagram clearly states the related item.

If I were modeling this, I would probably elect for a small change in data model.

```
@Entity
public class Receipt {
  @ManyToOne
  private Order order;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "receipt")
  private List<ReceiptItem> entries;
}

@Entity
public class ReceiptItem {
  @ManyToOne
  private Receipt receipt;

  @ManyToOne
  private Item item;
}

@Entity
public class Item {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item")
  private List<ReceiptItem> receipts;
}
```

The big important factor here is that both `Item` and `ReceiptItem` maintain a bidirectional relationship, which is owned by the `ReceiptItem`.

This relationship should allow you to display the `Receipt` and its associated `ReceiptItem` rows and include any pertinent information about an `Item`.  But it also allows you to render your `Order` and the appropriate `Item` rows with the pertinent information about the item's receipts.